# Business Objects - calculate percentage in report

Tags: reporting, business-objects

For example, I have such data set vizualized in report window:

```
~ 2013-02-01 2013-02-02 2013-02-03
A 10         1          5
B 20         2          45
C 70         2          0
```

but I want to show this in my report in shares like

```
~ 2013-02-01 2013-02-02 2013-02-03
A 10%        20%        10%
B 20%        40%        90%
C 70%        40%        0%
```

Which formula (or something) should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: The question is too unclear. What have you tried already? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Change the format for that column......change number format as percentage....then you will get it...